Deleting all subkeys in regedit with powershell
I want to delete all the subkeys of this path
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds

Here I have {E3CA8511-C9A2-4B55-A008-E2823464A6C0} which needs to be deleted.

But I could have something else as a name
When I type:
Get-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\*"

or the following
Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\*" -Recurse

I don't get anything in return. It seems like it's not existent from powershell's point of view.
And when I type:
Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\{E3CA8511-C9A2-4B55-A008-E2823464A6C0}"

It says that the path doesn't exist, although it actually exists.

I've searched this article:
and also this article about recreating the key, and it actually recreates the key in powershell but still doesn't delete it in the registery:
Here the example:
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\{E3CA8511-C9A2-4B55-A008-E2823464A6C0}" -Force
Remove-Item -Path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\{E3CA8511-C9A2-4B55-A008-E2823464A6C0}" -Recurse

Any ideas why this is happening and how to solve it?

To avoid confusion: Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\*" -Recurse and Remove-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\{E3CA8511-C9A2-4B55-A008-E2823464A6C0}" should work (in case of success, there is no output by design). However, the path you actually used when you got the error, per your screenshot, was HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\{E3CA8511-C9A2-4B55-A008-E2823464A6C0}, i.e. a registry-native path; ditto in the last snippet. The answer explains why registry-native paths cannot be used directly.


The path passed to Remove-Item in your last snippet, as also shown in the screenshot, is incorrect:
Remove-Item -Path "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\..." cannot work, because you can not use a native registry path that starts with a hive name such as HKEY_CURRENT_USER directly, as PowerShell will interpret it as a relative file-system path.[1]
Instead, you must:

Either: Start the path with the corresponding PowerShell drive specification, but note that only the HKEY_CURRENT_USER and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry hives have corresponding drives, HKCU: and HKLM:.

Or: Prepend the name of the registry provider to the registry-native path, separated with :: (e.g., registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ or, using the provider's full (module-qualified) name for robustness, Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\)[2]


Thus, to delete all subkeys of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds, use one of the following:
# Use PowerShell's HKCU: drive to target the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive.
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\*'

# Alternatively, prepend the provider prefix to the native registry path:
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force 'registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Workspaces\Feeds\*'


[1] The only exception is if PowerShell's  current location happens to be the root of that very hive (e.g., only after executing Set-Location HKCU:\, does something like Get-ChildItem HKEY_CURRENT_USER\ happen to work
[2] Note that the Core part of Microsoft.PowerShell.Core is unrelated to the to the PowerShell (Core) 7 edition of PowerShell. Microsoft.PowerShell.Core is simply the name of a built-in module that is present in both PowerShell editions (i.e. also in Windows PowerShell).
